# How can I remove the pattern that are matched from original file

Tags: perl

How can I remove the matched pattern that I print in output file from the original file. I used below script to print out all matched into the FILE6

```
open FILE4,'<RM' or die $!;
open FILE5,'<OR' or die $!;
open FILE6, '>Compare3.txt' or die $!;

my @array3 = <FILE4>;
my @array4 = <FILE5>;

foreach $x (@array3) {
    if($x =~ /(\S+) (\d+) (\S+)/) {
        $temp_allreg = $3; 
        foreach $y (@array4) {
            if($y =~ /\b$temp_allreg\b/i) {
                print FILE6 "$x$y\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on above coding, I print out the matched data from 2 file to the output file which is FILE6. So how to modify this code to remove matched pattern that print out in FILE 6 from original file which is FILE4 and FILE5. So that FILE4 and FILE5 only leave the pattern/data that are not matched.

Comment: Please fix your indenting and add the missing `}`

Comment: @ikegami i already fix the missing }

Comment: Well, no, you did it 16 minutes after. And you still haven't fixed the indenting

Comment: what do you mean  by identing @ikegami?

Comment: There, did it for you. Your code was simply unreadable

Comment: thanks. by the way do know how to modify my coding based on what i mention above @ikegami?

Comment: Why did you pick the names `FILE4`, `array3` and `x` to refer to the same thing!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $rm_qfn  = 'RM';
my $or_qfn  = 'OR';
my $out_qfn = 'Compare3.txt';

open(my $rm_fh, '<', $rm_qfn)
    or die("Can't open \"$rm_qfn\": $!\n");
open(my $or_fh, '<', $or_qfn)
    or die("Can't open \"$or_qfn\": $!\n");

open(my $out_fh, '>', $out_qfn)
    or die("Can't create \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");
open(my $out_rm_fh, '>', "$rm_qfn.tmp")
    or die("Can't create \"$rm_qfn.tmp\": $!\n");
open(my $out_or_fh, '>', "$or_qfn.tmp")
    or die("Can't create \"$or_qfn.tmp\": $!\n");

chomp( my @ors = <$or_fh> );

my @matched_ors;
while (my $rm = <$rm_fh>) {
    chomp($rm);
    my $matched_rm = 0;

    if (my ($all_reg) = $rm =~ /\S+ \d+ (\S+)/) {
        for my $or_idx (0..$#ors) {
            my $or = $ors[$or_idx];
            if ($or =~ /\b\Q$all_reg\E\b/i) {
                ++$matched_rm;
                ++$matched_ors[$or_idx];
                print($out_fh "$rm$or\n");
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$matched_rm) {
        print($out_rm_fh "$rm\n");
    }
}

close($rm_fh);
close($or_fh);

for my $or_idx (0..$#ors) {
    if (!$matched_ors[$or_idx]) {
        my $or = $ors[$or_idx];
        print($out_or_fh "$or\n");
    }
}

close($out_rm_fh);
close($out_or_fh);

rename("$rm_qfn.tmp", $rm_qfn)
   or die("Can't rename \"$rm_qfn.tmp\" to \"$rm_qfn\": $!\n");
rename("$or_qfn.tmp", $or_qfn)
   or die("Can't rename \"$or_qfn.tmp\" to \"$or_qfn\": $!\n");
```

Comment: I already run it and it success like what i want. Thanks for your help @ikegami

Comment: @ozzy: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @ChankeyPathak okay done mark it..thanks for remind me because i'am still new on these :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the same loop?

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
my $data = read_file $filename, {binmode => ':utf8'};

foreach $x (@array3) {
    if($x =~ /(\S+) (\d+) (\S+)/) {
        $temp_allreg = $3; 
        foreach $y (@array4) {
            if($y =~ /\b$temp_allreg\b/i){
                #print to output file
                print FILE6 "$x$y\n";
                #remove from input file
                $data =~ s/$x$y//g;
                write_file $filename, {binmode => ':utf8'}, $data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Since you can't use [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) module, you can consider writing those subroutines yourself.

```
sub read_file {
    my ($filename) = @_;

    open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die "Could not open '$filename' for reading $!";
    local $/ = undef;
    my $all = <$in>;
    close $in;

    return $all;
}

sub write_file {
    my ($filename, $content) = @_;

    open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die "Could not open '$filename' for writing $!";;
    print $out $content;
    close $out;

    return;
}
```

See: [How to replace a string in a file [perlmaven]](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-perl)

Comment: I can't use the File::Slurp, is there other way than use that one. thanks